# windows how to show memory segment of a process?

Tags: executable, objdump, dumpbin, readelf

We have tools like **objdump**, **readelf**, and **dumbin** to show **executable** file contents.

But when an **executable** file is loaded into memory (a **process** is created), the **segments** in memory is usually different from the **segments** in the **executable** file. For example, when loaded, two extra segments namely **stack** and **heap** are allocated (we overlook details of page mapping here).

Is there a tool that help show the in-time memory segment/status of a **process**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows executables use the [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format.  This format describes *sections* of memory that are allocated when the process is loaded, and optionally raw data (`.text`, `.data` sections) to be loaded into those sections.

Each section will typically have a *file offset* specifying where in the raw file the data is located, and a *Virtual Address* at which the data will be loaded.  These may or may not resemble each other.

[PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) can give you details on the sections (and everything else about a PE file) of an executable.

[Immunity Debugger](https://www.immunityinc.com/products/debugger/) will allow you to attach to a running process and see its [memory map](http://www.romhack.net/public/WindowsLiveWriter_Thelunaticmemorybufferoverflowbug_11333_MemoryMap1_thumb_1.png).

Comment: Thx for late response.I was away for other business. PE is very expensive. I just want to learn program by myself. I am trying to find any free software or embedded tools. By the way, do you know any tool for ELF under linux?

Comment: It seems that Immunity Debugger is for python language. Not for C/C++!

Comment: @Zack Um, not at all. Immunity is for *any* compiled Windows (PE) executable (regardless of language) - it deals with programs at the assembly code level.

Comment: @Zack I'm not really sure what you're trying to learn/accomplish. If you just want to learn how to program under Windows or Linux, then I think you're digging in way too deep at this time.